# Error 500 on deploying a Laravel 7 app, can someone help me?

Tags: laravel, hosting

I am trying to deploy a laravel 7 app but I am getting the 500 error.
The project works fine on local.
I've already changed the server php version and changed the public folder content location into the root folder but still nothing. I've also tryed to change the htaccess file but nothing.
It's the second day that I'm stuck in this problem please help me!!!

Comment: Look at the error log. A 500 means server error, so for us to help you we need to know what that error is.

Comment: It says net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: That's the error in your browser. Check the actual Laravel logs in storage/logs. First guess is that you don't have an .env file, or an APP_KEY set in your .env file.

Comment: There can be multiple reasons. Did you check your logs inside laravel application inside storage ? Did you add .env file to your production?

Comment: I voted to close this question because a 500 error is a very generic "something went wrong" error. It could be a misconfiguration, a permissions problem, or a coding error. More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Any answers here will be guesses and there are hundreds if not thousands of possible answers.

Answer (score 3):

I always recommend turning on the debug functionality to actually see the error you are getting rather than the typical 500 Error page.

> Note: don't set `APP_DEBUG` to `true` on production.

change the below in `.env` :

```
APP_DEBUG=true
```

Keep in mind, that the actual error should be written to `storage/logs/laravel.logs` by default.

**Most Common Reasons:**

- `.env` not found.
- Database connecton issue.
- you didnt run `composer install`.
- No `APP_KEY` which you will need to run `php artisan key:generate` for.
- Permission issues.

After any changes in the `.env` , run the commands below:

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
```